# Disable internet access but keep LAN access on Linux Distro

Tags: linux, networking, internet

I have 4 ethernet interfaces and 1 Wifi interface that are part of a board that has internet access which runs a linux OS.  I would like to remove access to the internet from the ethernet interfaces while still enabling those clients to ping/communicate with the other subnets on both Wifi and ethernet clients.

This ideally should work regardless if the IP addresses are statically set or DHCP enabled.  The board has this capability.

Please help.

Comment: Why not just remove the gateway?

Comment: Would removing the gateway negate the ability for the client to ping other subnets on the other interfaces?

Comment: As it turns out, removing the gateway only works for statically set IP addresses.  Which is great.  However, if the client enables DHCP IPv4, the board assigns a gateway which enables internet access.  I want this to function without having the user to manually removing the assigned gateway address during DHCP.  Moreover, removing the gateway does in fact remove the ability from the client to ping/COMM to any other clients on the different subnets.

Comment: Just set up an `onup`-action to remove the default route!

Comment: Sorry @EugenRieck, I'm unfamiliar with onup.  Could you provide a link for clarification?

Comment: That depends on your distro - if network config is `/etc/network/interfaces`-based use `post-up route del ...`

Answer (score -1):

You could write iptables firewall rules to drop all traffic that doesn't match the ones listed in the [reserved IP addresses list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses). You don't have to put everything from that list in your rules though, just the subnets you want to grant access to.

Something like this would restrict traffic to only the 192.168.0.0/16 subnet:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Comment: Would these iptables rules work with either static or DHCP enabled IP addresses?  The ethernet configurations can be set to either or.

Comment: Would this also remove internet access on the ethernet interfaces?

Comment: It will work regardless of static or dynamic IP. It will remove internet access on all interfaces. You can specify which interface you would like the rules to apply to by using the -i flag in iptables.

Comment: This will horribly break on the very often used 10.x.y.z private nets, locking out the user

Comment: @EugenRieck that's why I specified this is only an example. It will need to be tailored for OP's specific network setup.

Comment: Instead of using the IP address, which users can freely change, will this method work using the physical name instead?  e.g. eh0, wlan0 etc.

Comment: @John I don't quite understand what you are asking. The user's IP address has nothing to do with this. These commands are used to block everything, and allow specific subnets to pass.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was asking if: iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
could instead be: iptables -A INPUT -s wlan0 -j ACCEPT?

Would this work for both input/output?

Comment: @John No, it wouldn't work. Let me break down what the commands are doing

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
This allows traffic coming in from 192.168.0.0/16

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
This denies all incoming traffic

iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
This allows outgoing traffic to 192.168.0.0/16

iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
This denies all outgoing traffic

Since iptables rules are parsed top to bottom, the first one that it hits will apply. This means that all traffic to/from 192.168.0.0/16 will be allowed, and it will block all other traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  This does work, however, it blocks the internet from clients on the wlan0 (Wi-Fi Interface) as well.  The 4 ethernet clients should be able to communicate with clients on Wi-Fi, however the ethernet clients shouldn't have internet access while the Wi-Fi clients should.

Is this possible?